# How to view the mobile version of Wikia articles?

Tags: mobile, wikia

On Wikipedia, I can read the mobile version of the pages by changing the URL from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spice into http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spice

I wonder if I can do something like that on Wikia too.

For example, I would like to see the mobile version of the page http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/StarCraft

Comment: Wikia serves the mobile version based on the User agent. You'll need a user agent spoofer to be served the mobile version

Answer (score 3):

[Wikia](http://www.wikia.com) has a [mobile application](http://www.wikia.com/Mobile) you can try out. However if you do not have an Apple product this is not very helpful.

If you are on a mobile device trying to view the page you should be automatically switched to the mobile skin based on your user agent.

As you can see in the image below, I am emulating using a [Nexus 5](http://www.google.ca/nexus/5/) phone to browse Wikia and it has given me the correct mobile site.

[image: nexus 5 mobile]

Comment: thanks, how do you emulate that? Do you know some Google Chrome extension that can emulate a mobile phone / tablet? I just tried this extension: "Mobile/Responsive Web Design Tester" but it shows the same site scaled to a lower resolution. Didn't changed the ink/background color to black/white.

Comment: @BearBear no extension needed here. Just open up Chromes developer tools (F12) and hit the phone icon near the top left of the panel that opens. Then select the phone you want to emulate. In my case the Nexus 5. And then reload the page and Wikia should be in mobile mode.

Comment: Sorry where is that phone icon? I got a menu "Elements" - "Network" - "Sources" - "Timeline" - "Profiles" - "Resources" etc. Could not see any phone icon

Comment: @BearBear there is a nice tutorial here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

Answer (score 2):

I was reading a wikia page with an Asus Memo Pad tablet and I could switch to mobile site/full site. When I switched to mobile site, it added to the url the following: "?useskin=wikiamobile"

Therefore the solution seems to be to change

http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/StarCraft

into

http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/StarCraft?useskin=wikiamobile